# Bar Plot from a dictionary with tuple keys

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, plotly

I have a dictionary with tuple as keys, like shown below:

```
{('Friday', 0): 108, ('Friday', 1): 110, ('Friday', 2): 75, ... ('Sunday', 23): 120}
```

I`m trying to build a Bar plot, that with the dictionary keys in x axis and dictionary values in Y axis:

```
trace0 = go.Bar(
    x=pump_dry_day_beh_dic.keys(),
    y=pump_dry_day_beh_dic.values(),
    name ='yyy'

)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1, specs=[[{}]],
                          shared_xaxes=True, shared_yaxes=True,
                          vertical_spacing=0.001)

fig.append_trace(trace0, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=1000,  title='xxx')
fig['layout']['xaxis1'].update(title='day-hour')
fig['layout']['yaxis1'].update(title='Values')
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename=' xxx')
```

But I`m getting the following error:

```
 The 'x' property is an array that may be specified as a tuple,
    list, numpy array, or pandas Series
```

On the other hand, if I change the above code to the code below, I have as result an empty plot.

```
   x=list(pump_dry_day_beh_dic.keys()),
    y=list(pump_dry_day_beh_dic.values()),
    name ='yyyy'
```

Is there a way how I can solve this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have `pandas` tag here...

```
import pandas as pd

pump_dry_day_beh_dic = {('Friday', 0): 108, ('Friday', 1): 110, 
                        ('Friday', 2): 75, ('Sunday', 23): 120}
pd.DataFrame([pump_dry_day_beh_dic]).T.plot.bar()
```

[image]